# How can I make personal notes on the map?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'd like to be able to add my own notes and comments to locations in Skyrim - for example "There's a bandit leader here whom I couldn't kill yet - come back later to finish the job". How can I do that? Mods are an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mod that allows it indeed, you can download it from here:

http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/38731/

The features list:

- You can place your own markers with your own, self-written notes attached to them.
- Up to 60 custom markers (if you want more, it's easy to add more in Creation Kit).
- You can fast travel to your markers.
- You can edit and remove your markers.
- Works with SkyUi's Location Finder.
- First line of your note become a marker name (displayed on the map and in Location Finder).
- English and Polish localizations.

As you see, it is only available in English or Polish so this might conflict if your game is in a different language. However, you can instruct Steam to change the language of the game in the game's properties menu.

Comment: There is need to edit the link out. Thank you. Please refrain from re-editing.

Comment: It looks better to have a link instead of a URL in the middle of the post

Comment: As per the rules, you are not allowed to re-edit if the author rejected the edit. Therefore I ask you to move on and leave my answer alone. It is a minor edit that is not allowed anyway.

Comment: @JoethePerson Don't start a rollback war here. Please. @Assylum, do note that the edits in question were valid, and they *were not* removing the link from your post, but instead moving it to within the text of your answer. [like this.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/155178/3129). I'd encourage you to do so yourself, because it really does look better and improve readability. You can do this with the WYSIWIG editor, or, if you'd prefer to know the markdown yourself, it takes the form of `[wordwordswords](http://URLGOESHERE.COM)`.

Comment: @Assylum [here is the editing page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/editing)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I don't like hiding links behind text. Plain and simple. I don't see how this contributes to my answer in any way.

Comment: You realize you can see where a link leads by hovering the cursor over it, right?

Comment: I guess that's close enough. I though about adding a custom note to each location on the map, but I guess that's not possible.